# How to handle back-end response translations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I'm working on a Java-based back-end project for an international client.

The back-end sends several messages to the front-end indicating failures or success.

The client wants these messages to be available in 2 other languages.

I don't want to hard-code these translations as these messages can change over time.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

P.S. This is a microservices based project using Spring Boot.

Comment: There are several options which would also depend on your environment (e.g. UI capabilities) and requirements. If you don't want to hard-code the messages you could deploy the translations in configuration files (e.g. .properties) or even in some database (and potentially cache them in memory). Then let the caller provide a language to get the messages in - but I'd still send unique ids for consumption by the machine and potential (re-translation) by the client.

Answer (score 0):

Look into MessageSource:

> MessageSource is used for resolving messages, with support for the
> parameterization and internationalization of the messages. Spring
> contains two built-in MessageSource implementations:
> ResourceBundleMessageSource and
>
> ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.
> The latter is able to reload message definitions without restarting
> the Virtual Machine.

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;



logger.info("{}", messageSource.getMessage("l2",
    new Object[] {"Paul Smith"}, Locale.GERMAN));
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html